# What is an Oort Cloud?

Tags: solar-system

New to astronomy ! I have been reading some astronomical books, but suddenly I came across the word Oort cloud, So, what is an Oort cloud ?

Comment: Where did you come across this word.  In a book, or a website. Please tell which book or website.  Have you tried a quick web search?  There is no point in repeating what you already know, or what you can very easily find out.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it lacks effort. A simple Google search could have answered the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Oort cloud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oort_cloud) is  the (assumed) cloud of pristine objects at the edge of the solar systems beyond >1000AU, the source of long-period comets. It's named after the Dutch astronomer Jan Oort who postulated its existence.